# Practical difference between TCP and Subscriber timeout

Tags: spring-webflux

What is the tangible difference between a TCP timeout on Webflux WebCllient, e.g. set so:

```
 HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
            .tcpConfiguration(client ->
                    client.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10000)
                    .doOnConnected(conn -> conn
                            .addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(10))
                            .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(10))));

    ClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient.wiretap(true));       

    return WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:3000")
            .clientConnector(connector)
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .build();
```

And timeout on the Subscriber level

```
webClient.post()
            .uri("/employees")
            .body(Mono.just(empl), Employee.class)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Employee.class)
            .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(10000));
```

I plan to set the timeout on a per-request basis, so it seems more effective to go for option 1, where I don't create the whole HTTP client for each request, but maybe there are some caveats or negative side effects related to this approach?

Comment: tcp timeout is timeout on a network level when doing a request somewhere, timeout on the publisher is the time it is allowed to take without anything getting emitted from the publisher.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but practically what does it mean? Should I be aware of any specific consequences when using one and not the other